# Service Console Tab Name

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow, service-cloud-console

I have called flow in the URL button. When I click on the button, a new tab is opened and flow is initiated but the tab name is displayed as Task. Is there any way to change the tab name in Service Console?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, You cannot.

**Workaround:**

You can use the URL button to load an Aura component with [lightning:isUrlAddressable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:isUrlAddressable/documentation) interface. You should give url like `/lightning/cmp/c__MyComponent` and then in component, on init, invoke flow and also change the label using [workspaceApi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:workspaceAPI/documentation). Below is sample code:

COMPONENT:

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable"
                access="GLOBAL">

    <lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <lightning:flow aura:id="flowData"/>

</aura:component>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
doInit: function (component, event, helper) {
    component.find("flowData").startFlow("Quick_Account"); // API name of flow

    var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
    workspaceAPI.isConsoleNavigation().then(function(isCon) {
        console.log('isCon => ', JSON.stringify(isCon));
        workspaceAPI.getFocusedTabInfo().then(function(response) {
            var focusedTabId = response.tabId;
            workspaceAPI.setTabLabel({
                tabId: focusedTabId,
                label: "Focused Tab"
            });
            workspaceAPI.setTabIcon({
                tabId: focusedTabId, 
                icon: "utility:account",
                iconAlt: "New Account"
            });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    });
},
```